# Toggle Button to set SESSION value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, session

On my website I wanted to have the option for the user to toggle language of their session. Click and the language goes from English to French.

The problem is that I want the user to be able to just click on a button to change things to French. once SESSION is set to FR the current page index.php will change to french when it reloads

How I want it to work:

index.php page loads and the  `$_SESSION['lang'] == en` (already set)

User clicks on toggle and `$_SESSION['lang'] = "fr"`  and the page reloads.

User clicks on the toggle again and `$_SESSION['lang'] = en` and the page reloads.

etc. etc.

Comment: ok, and the problem is? what did you try already? where is the problem?

Comment: I tried some ajax stuff which didn't work... The problem is I have code that would work but it requires admin user status and an account in our DB. This particular user will not have that luxury so I want them to just set it for the current session .. Not sure if this is making any sense .

Comment: The problem is that I want the user to be able to just click on a button to change things to French.  once SESSION is set to FR the current page index.php will change to french when it reloads

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On index.php, put a link:

```
<a href="language.php">Toggle Language</a>
```

In language.php, use this code to change the session variable:

```
<?php
session_start();

if($_SESSION['lang'] == 'en') 
  $_SESSION['lang'] = 'fr';

elseif($_SESSION['lang'] == 'fr') //else could be used here instead of elseif
  $_SESSION['lang'] = 'en';

// return to index.php
header("location:index.php");
exit();
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for responding!  This seems close but all I need is the session value to change and to refresh the page to reflect the change . Idon't have a language.php page either.

Comment: OOooh I think you are saying to create that language.php page?

Comment: Yes, create language.php. The toggle link will take the user to language.php which sets the session variable, then redirects back to index.php.